# How to convert a single 'dicted' list to json?

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I am using SQLalchemy and flask API to develop my school project,
the original code:

```
@app.route('/test/',methods=['GET'])
def search_item():
    result=engine.execute(
    'SQL query codes'
    )
    test=result.fetchall()
    ...
    return tmp
```

for the ... part above I have tried following steps, and this is the data looks like, which I have fetched from the db and converted to list.

```
test=[('01','Bob','Engineer','M'),('02','Jacob','Cook','M'),('03','Amy','Teacher','F')]
```

I appended the index by using for loop and i=i+1 method, since looks like you can directly transfer dict to json.

```
test=[0,('01','Bob','Engineer','M'),1,('02','Jacob','Cook','M'),2,('03','Amy','Teacher','F')]
```

and it successfully converted to dict like below, by using:

```
sh=iter(test)
test=dict(zip(sh,sh))
```

output, and I have checked the type(test) is dict:

```
test={0:('01','Bob','Engineer','M'),1:('02','Jacob','Cook','M'),2:('03','Amy','Teacher','F')}
```

but when I want to convert it to json, error happened, it shows this error message:

```
TypeError: Object of type LegacyRow is not JSON serializable
```

I am using this code for converting json:

```
tmp=json.dumps(test)
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result you get from your query gets printed as if it is a tuple, but in reality it is of type  LegacyRow causing an error later.

Try to do this after fetching the result:

```
test=[tuple(elem for elem in item) for item in test]
```

`test` should look the same but now you have actual tuples that are serializable.